# Creating new worksheets in same order they appear on a list

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet

I want to create new worksheets from a list in my first worksheet. I normally call this worksheet "cover" or "summery"

```
Sub CreateSheets()
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
On Error GoTo Errorhandling
Set rng = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select cell range:", _
  Title:="Create sheets", _
  Default:=Selection.Address, Type:=8)
For Each cell In rng
    If cell <> "" Then
        Sheets.Add.Name = cell
    End If
Next cell
Errorhandling:
End Sub
```

This makes the new worksheets in reverse. Say my selection is cells C1 through C10. It will label the first new worksheet with the C10 value, the 2nd with the C9 value etc. It also moves my "cover" or "summery" sheet to the end of the worksheet tabs list.

How do I add new worksheets after the existing one rather than before it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = cell